# How to use stop() method in the SoundPool class?

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I want to play a sound when a button is held in, but when I release the button I want the same sound to stop playing. Like so:

```
        private final SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);          

        ...

        btn1_row1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                sp.play(sndTest, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                sp.stop(sndTest); // It requires a Stream ID, not a Sound ID
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I have tried the following

```
final int streamId = sp.play(sndTest, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

sp.stop(streamId);
```

But it doesn't seem to work, If anyone could help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, since i declared the stream ID as a final, I could'nt initialize my it's variable in the onTouchListener(), so I instead declared it as a static int, like so:

```
static int streamID;

...

btn1_row1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            sndTestID = sp.play(sndTest, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

        } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            sp.stop(sndTestID);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```